# Pass non strongly-typed parameter from Controller to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

It's well known how to pass strongly typed objects to Views or by using Viewbags but how to you pass data to a view if I just want to send a simple string ?

```
public ActionResult Index()
{ return View("View","TextParameter"};
```

and a View...

```
<h2>This is my TextParameter = ??  <-- what goes here ?
```

Seems to be such a small and easy thing but I'm having a brain fart and can't find it in Google. Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`<%= Model %>`, or `@Model` if you're using Razor.  I only tried it using Razor, so can't guarantee that the ASPX version works although I can't see why it wouldn't.  I did have to cast the string to `object` in order to ensure the correct view was used, though (otherwise the second string is interpreted as the master template name):

```
return View("Foo", (object)"Bar, Baz, Quux");
```

Comment: I use Razor too but @ Model...That's assume that you're using a strong typed variable. Then you get Intellisense available as well @Model.StringWhatever. Or am I missing something ?

Comment: Depends how you've defined your view, I used `@model System.String`, as I'd assumed that you wanted just to pass a simple string to the view.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your views add this:

For ASPX View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<string>" %>
```

For Razor View:

```
@model string
```

Then pass it in as Ade described above